# Does QGraphicsScene, or QGraphicsItem, store scene coordinates?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I programmatically move the items in my `QGraphicsScene` and they end up in the wrong places. They end up at coordinates (2x, 2y), instead of (x, y).

Somewhere I am changing the wrong thing. 
I work both with the scene and with individual items, accessing both through pointers.

`QGraphicsItem::pos()` can give you the position in scene coordinates (it has no parent).
`QGraphicsScene` holds a list of all the items within the scene:
`QList<QGraphicsItem *> QGraphicsScene::items () const`.

**My question**: the information of where an item is on the scene - is it stored within the scene or within the item?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the actual code you used to set the item position. We are not physics. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In item i.e. in qgraphicsitem pimpl class. Open qgraphicsitem_p.h and there you will find QPointF pos member.

Comment: Thank you, nomenas. I did find a QPointF pos member in qgraphicsitem_p.h. Should the scene coordinates change ... all items within the scene would have to have these values updated, I guess.

Comment: In furtherance of this, I found that QGraphicsScene bases its item index on QGraphicsItem::boundingRect() (it's actually virtual). I presume the item index is useful for finding items.